# image saving from a URL problem

Tags: c#, image, url

I am trying to download an image from URL:
http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/servedimages/340582.png?t=2

I am using `HttpWebRequest`   `webRespose`   `Stream`   `BinaryReader`   `FileStream`   `BinaryWriter`

this works for other websites and images but the url I gave on the above gives me an empty 0 byte file..

which means I cannot save the image from that URL.

Is there anybody who can help me?

Comment: You can just right-click on the image and save it to your hard disk :)

Comment: no, I am just trying it now, Chris. The thing is when I am trying to open this image on my browser it tells me that I need to install quicktimes plugin..I can see the images but when I copy and paste the direct link it tells me to install that plugin.

Comment: Something is obviously wrong with your code, but if you don't post it, it's hard to tell what is wrong...

Comment: Are you running this on a mobile device? My simple C# file downloader is able to grab that file without trouble. Your best bet is to single-step this in the debugger so you can see where the problem is. If you want more help, you'll have to show us some code.

Comment: Jim I am running the code on a PC. The solution Thomas offered worked fine. It lets me download the image file. However, I need to get the image file to an image object. Is there a method to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am using HttpWebRequest webRespose Stream BinaryReader FileStream BinaryWriter

Why use 6 different classes when you can do the same with only one?

```
string sourceUrl = "http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/servedimages/340582.png?t=2";
string localPath = @"C:\foo\bar\340582.png";
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.DownloadFile(sourceUrl, localPath);
}
```

If you need to load an image from this URL, you can do that (I assume you're using WinForms/GDI):

```
string sourceUrl = "http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/servedimages/340582.png?t=2";
string localPath = @"C:\foo\bar\340582.png";
Image image;
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
using (Stream stream = wc.OpenRead(sourceUrl))
{
    image = Image.FromStream(stream);
}
```

Comment: you are the hero Thomas! it worked like a charm ;) however I need to get that to an Image img = wc.MethodName; how can I attain the image to an Image object?

Comment: Your answers are great especially Thomas' method worked very fine with too few lines of codes.

However I need to attain the image from url to another image object. Is there a way to do that without downloading the file. I am sorry about my first question. I asked in a wrongly way and it is my mistake. Your answers are just perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you have hit their site way too many times and they are now blocking you for abuse...

Most likely they are examining the headers sent and not allowing bots to grab their intellectual property.

Two possible solutions come to mind:

1. Change your request code to pass believable browser headers.
2. Call blackberry.com and get permission to reuse their files.

You should probably do both.

Point is, I doubt it's a code issue and more likely a violation of their terms of service.

---

and for fun:

```
HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
// Setting the useragent seems to resolve certain issues that *may* crop up. 
httpRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";
```

Comment: thanks but how can I change my request code to believable browser headers?

Comment: HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) HTtpWebRequest.Create(imageUrl);
webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1);

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this out and this downloaded and saved the image for me. You will probably need to check for MIME types and all that somewhere along the road.

```
string url = "http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/servedimages/340582.png?t=2";

using (System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(WebRequest.Create(url).GetResponse().GetResponseStream())) {
    img.Save("new.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Kluminotty, many thanks friend Your answer solved out my problem

Comment: Not a problem, I saw this post and realized I had just went through this a few weeks ago on a web app I am completing. Knowledge not shared is knowledge lost.